# How to get date time with time zone as string from sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am using postgresql db with sqlalchemy

When I use the query `select now()` directly I get a result that can be converted into string, but I can't produce this output using sqlalchemy.

Already I have used the following module which is not giving me the result I needed 
from sqlalchemy: `import func`

Answer (score 3):

The `func` module is a proxy that creates functions.  So `func.now()` will produce the column you want.

```
now = session.query(func.now()).scalar()
```

This returns a Python datetime object.